# awk print getting error - not enough arguments to satisfy format string

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am getting below error for awk print

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `MiNirzRjlOth%ER48R6K0SGDY!'
                     ^ ran out for this one
```

code using

```
ABC=`echo ${ABC1}| awk '{printf $NF}'`
```

where the value of ABC1 is random string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` in awk is to print something using a format template. [Documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html). If  you just want to print the variable as is, you don't need to use this.

You have specified `$NF` - which is "variable number equal to count of variables", effectively "last variable".

In your case you can one of the following, which will give the same result:

```
 `awk '{print $NF}'`  
 MiNirzRjlOth%ER48R6K0SGDY!
```

or using formatting. For strings code `%s` is used.

```
 `awk '{printf "%s", $NF}'`
 MiNirzRjlOth%ER48R6K0SGDY!
```

Using `printf` has the advantage that you can pad with data, left/right adjust and much more.

Comment: `$NF` is the last field in the line, which is quite likely what OP intended.

Comment: @rici you are probably correct here, thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

Never do `printf input_data` for any input data ($1, $NF, $0, or any variable that holds previously read input data) as it'll fail when your input data contains printf formatting chars like `%s`, as you're now seeing with `%E...` appearing in your input. Do `printf "%s", input_data` instead.